# How to hide, encrypt and password protect a volume on my smartphone?

Tags: android, encryption

I want to have a hidden volume on my smartphone which is encrypted and password protected.

Once you encrypt a file, this will happen:

1. new encrypted file will be created
2. original file will safely be deleted

When you later want to view, edit or use the encrypted file, a new un-encrypted version will be created.

Considering the single channel - read OR write - operation of the internal flash memory of mobile devices, this will be a very slow and battery consuming process.

On-the-fly encryption is not possible since the phone lacks a dedicated on-board encryption processor (with a boot loader verification method) and/or some really fast multi-channel memory.

Does anyone know a better way to do this?

Comment: Android and iPhone are non-overlapping areas. Is this an iPhone question or an Android question? Are you writing an app? Or are you looking for an app?

Comment: I want to make an app for rooted Android phones and later also for iOS. Think that the problem is OS independent.

Comment: It's not OS independent at all. Android has asec containers with on-the-fly encryption in the kernel.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Android has support for encrypted mounts in the kernel (the Linux `dm-crypt` code). The `vold` volume manager supports mounting a file as an encrypted partition. You can find more details in the [notes](http://source.android.com/tech/encryption/android_crypto_implementation.html).

[LUKSManager](http://nemesis2.qx.net/pages/LUKSManager) does exactly this.